# How to implement a two way jsonrpc + twisted server/client

Tags: python, twisted, microcontroller, json-rpc

Hello I am working on develop a rpc server based on twisted to serve several microcontrollers which make rpc call to twisted jsonrpc server. But the application also required that server send information to each micro at any time, so the question is how could be a good practice to prevent that the response from a remote jsonrpc call from a micro be confused with a server jsonrpc request which is made for a user.

The consequence that I am having now is that micros are receiving bad information, because they dont know if netstring/json string that is comming from socket is their response from a previous requirement or is a new request from server.

Here is my code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from txjsonrpc.netstring import jsonrpc
import weakref

creds  = {'user1':'pass1','user2':'pass2','user3':'pass3'}

class arduinoRPC(jsonrpc.JSONRPC):
    def connectionMade(self):
        pass

    def jsonrpc_identify(self,username,password,mac):
        """ Each client must be authenticated just after to be connected calling this rpc """
        if creds.has_key(username):
            if creds[username] == password:
                authenticated = True
            else:
                authenticated = False
        else:
            authenticated = False

        if authenticated:
            self.factory.clients.append(self)
            self.factory.references[mac] = weakref.ref(self)
            return {'results':'Authenticated as %s'%username,'error':None}
        else:
            self.transport.loseConnection()

    def jsonrpc_sync_acq(self,data,f):
        """Save into django table data acquired from sensors and send ack to gateway"""
        if not (self in self.factory.clients):
            self.transport.loseConnection()
        print f
        return {'results':'synced %s records'%len(data),'error':'null'}

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        """ mac address is searched and all reference to self.factory.clientes are erased """  
        for mac in self.factory.references.keys():
            if self.factory.references[mac]() == self:
                print 'Connection closed - Mac address: %s'%mac
                del self.factory.references[mac]
                self.factory.clients.remove(self)


class rpcfactory(jsonrpc.RPCFactory):
    protocol = arduinoRPC
    def __init__(self, maxLength=1024):
        self.maxLength = maxLength
        self.subHandlers = {}
        self.clients    =   []
        self.references =   {}

""" Asynchronous remote calling to micros, simulating random calling from server """
import threading,time,random,netstring,json
class asyncGatewayCalls(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,rpcfactory):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.rpcfactory =   rpcfactory
        """identifiers of each micro/client connected"""
        self.remoteMacList    =   ['12:23:23:23:23:23:23','167:67:67:67:67:67:67','90:90:90:90:90:90:90']
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
            while True:
                """ call to any of three potential micros connected """ 
                mac = self.remoteMacList[random.randrange(0,len(self.remoteMacList))]
                if self.rpcfactory.references.has_key(mac):
                    print 'Calling %s'%mac
                    proto   =   self.rpcfactory.references[mac]()
                    """ requesting echo from selected micro"""
                    dataToSend  = netstring.encode(json.dumps({'method':'echo_from_micro','params':['plop']}))
                    proto.transport.write(dataToSend)
                    break

factory = rpcfactory(arduinoRPC)

"""start thread caller""" 
r=asyncGatewayCalls(factory)
r.start()

reactor.listenTCP(7080, factory)
print "Micros remote RPC server started"
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a enough information to each message so that the recipient can determine how to interpret it.  Your requirements sounds very similar to those of [AMP](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.amp.html), so you could either use AMP instead or use the same structure as AMP to identify your messages.  Specifically:

- In requests, put a particular key - for example, AMP uses "_ask" to identify requests.  It also gives these a unique value, which further identifies that request for the lifetime of the connection.
- In responses, put a different key - for example, AMP uses "_answer" for this.  The value matches up with the value from the "_ask" key in the request the response is for.

Using an approach like this, you just have to look to see whether there is an "_ask" key or an "_answer" key to determine if you've received a new request or a response to a previous request.

On a separate topic, your `asyncGatewayCalls` class shouldn't be thread-based.  There's no apparent reason for it to use threads, and by doing so it is also misusing Twisted APIs in a way which will lead to undefined behavior.  Most Twisted APIs can only be used in the thread in which you called `reactor.run`.  The only exception is `reactor.callFromThread`, which you can use to send a message to the reactor thread from any other thread.  `asyncGatewayCalls` tries to write to a transport, though, which will lead to buffer corruption or arbitrary delays in the data being sent, or perhaps worse things.  Instead, you can write `asyncGatewayCalls` like this:

```
from twisted.internet.task import LoopingCall

class asyncGatewayCalls(object):
    def __init__(self, rpcfactory):
        self.rpcfactory = rpcfactory
        self.remoteMacList = [...]

    def run():
        self._call = LoopingCall(self._pokeMicro)
        return self._call.start(10)

    def _pokeMicro(self):
        while True:
            mac = self.remoteMacList[...]
            if mac in self.rpcfactory.references:
                proto = ...
                dataToSend = ...
                proto.transport.write(dataToSend)
                break

factory = ...
r = asyncGatewayCalls(factory)
r.run()

reactor.listenTCP(7080, factory)
reactor.run()
```

This gives you a single-threaded solution which should have the same behavior as you intended for the original `asyncGatewayCalls` class.  Instead of sleeping in a loop in a thread in order to schedule the calls, though, it uses the reactor's scheduling APIs (via the higher-level LoopingCall class, which schedules things to be called repeatedly) to make sure `_pokeMicro` gets called every ten seconds.

Comment: Yes your right, few hour ago I was making the same conclusion after reading thread API documentation (task.LoopingCall). I tested and it worked pretty good. Thank you for your help

Comment: Isn't the jsonrpc 'id' field suitable to determine which response is for which request?

Comment: JSON-RPC 2.0 messages can be clearly differentiated. Notifications - requests without id field, responses also not the same (result and error).